# Does google index pages with opacity:0 or hidden or display:none

Tags: html, indexing, seo, pagerank

Does google index pages with opacity:0 or hidden or display:none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [Fetch as Googlebot tool](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587) in [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) Labs. It is described by Google as a utility that will allow you to see how Googlebot sees web pages.

More information:

- [Fetch as Googlebot and Malware details -- now in Webmaster Tools Labs!](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/fetch-as-googlebot-and-malware-details.html)
- [GENERIC CIALIS on my website? I think my site has been hacked!](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/generic-cialis-on-my-website-i-think-my.html)

Comment: you told how to see the answer.. but not the answer itself! :(

Answer (score 0):

This is very [easily Googleable](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+display+none)... seems like they'll index the hidden parts, but may tend to rank them lower, especially if it looks like you're cloaking to game the search engine.

Answer (score 0):

John Mueller stated that content hidden from the user would be indexed but carry less weight than that visible to the user (https://youtu.be/zZAY-BwL6rU?t=406).

I thought the introduction of mobile-first indexing might have changed things but the testing I've done with new build sites on fresh domains suggests otherwise. I'm confident that significantly less weight is carried by elements with opacity 0, so where an element has value from an SEO perspective I'm happy to move it around but I won't fade it in.